# Извлечь из строк подстроку

Tags: python, pandas

Здравствуйте, надо из текстового файла извлечь все таймзоны[tz], где есть слово "Africa", получилось извлечь всей таймзоны(в другой программе), теперь надо чисто с Африкой)

Пример строки

> { "a": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   Trident/5.0)", "c": "ES", "nk": 0, "tz": "Africa/Ceuta", "gr": "51",
>   "g": "zQ95Hi", "h": "ytZYWR", "l": "jplnews", "al": "es-ES", "hh":
>   "bitly.com", "r": "http://www.facebook.com/", "u":
>   "http://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/imagesvideo/uranus.html", "t":
>   1331923265, "hc": 1331670549, "cy": "Alcal", "ll": [ 37.516701,
>   -5.983300 ] }

```
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json
from collections import Counter  
import numpy as np
import re

path='Test.txt'
open(path).readline()
records= [json.loads(line) for  line in open(path)]
time_zones = [rec['tz'] for rec in records if 'tz' in  rec]

counts = Counter(time_zones)  
ag_counts_africa = str(time_zones)
result = re.findall(r'Africa', ag_counts_africa)
print (result)

time_zones_africa = [rec for rec in result if ag_counts_africa in  rec]
print(time_zones_africa)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

Исходный JSON файл (я добавил еще одну строку с `"tz":"Europe/Berlin"`):

> [
>
> { "a": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   Trident/5.0)", "c": "ES", "nk": 0, "tz": "Africa/Ceuta", "gr": "51",
>   "g": "zQ95Hi", "h": "ytZYWR", "l": "jplnews", "al": "es-ES", "hh":
>   "bitly.com", "r": "http://www.facebook.com/", "u":
>   "http://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/imagesvideo/uranus.html", "t":
>   1331923265, "hc": 1331670549, "cy": "Alcal", "ll": [ 37.516701,
>   -5.983300 ] },
>
> { "a": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)", "c": "ES", "nk": 0, "tz": "Europe/Berlin", "gr": "51", "g": "zQ95Hi", "h": "ytZYWR", "l": "jplnews", "al":
>   "es-ES", "hh": "bitly.com", "r": "http://www.facebook.com/", "u":
>   "http://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/imagesvideo/uranus.html", "t":
>   1331923265, "hc": 1331670549, "cy": "Alcal", "ll": [ 37.516701,
>   -5.983300 ] }
>
> ]

Парсим JSON в Pandas DataFrame:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(open(r'D:\temp\.data\670454.json').read()))
```

DataFrame

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
                                                   a     al   c     cy       g  gr  \
0  Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT ...  es-ES  ES  Alcal  zQ95Hi  51
1  Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT ...  es-ES  ES  Alcal  zQ95Hi  51

        h          hc         hh        l                    ll  nk  \
0  ytZYWR  1331670549  bitly.com  jplnews  [37.516701, -5.9833]   0
1  ytZYWR  1331670549  bitly.com  jplnews  [37.516701, -5.9833]   0

                          r           t             tz  \
0  http://www.facebook.com/  1331923265   Africa/Ceuta
1  http://www.facebook.com/  1331923265  Europe/Berlin

                                                   u
0  http://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/imagesvideo/uranus...
1  http://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/imagesvideo/uranus...
```

Извлекаем и фильтруем временные зоны в виде `Pandas.Series`:

```
In [22]: df.loc[df['tz'].str.contains('Africa'), 'tz']
Out[22]:
0    Africa/Ceuta
Name: tz, dtype: object
```

в виде списка:

```
In [23]: df.loc[df['tz'].str.contains('Africa'), 'tz'].tolist()
Out[23]: ['Africa/Ceuta']
```

---

Если у вас вместо нормального JSON файла набор строк, каждая из которых это JSON, то можно поступить так:

```
d = []

with open(r'D:\temp\.data\670454.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        d.append(json.loads(line))

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```